# Does $\pi$ contain any zeroes?

Tags: number-theory, pi

Let's say we have two functions, $f$ and $g$. $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto [0,1]$ where $0,1$ denote true, false respectively. $f(x)=1$ when $x$ contains any zeroes as a digit; $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Now let's suppose that $g(x)$ essentially removed all numbers preceding the decimal point and the decimal itself  from $x$ (that is, $g(4.5)=5$, $g(e)=71828182\ldots$ etc.).

Would $f(g(\pi))=1$? That is, does the $g(\pi)$ contain any zeroes as a digit? Do you have any evidence to support your claim?

Comment: What are you asking? You need to clarify this question, especially your definiton of the function f..

Comment: This would have been a [fabulous question in 1630](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_computation_of_%CF%80)!

Comment: @MarkMcClure People say I'm rather old school for my age ;) Thanks for the reference!

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A050279, which shows the start of the positions of 0, 00, 000, ... in the decimal expansion of pi.

Comment: $\pi$, *e*, and other famous irrationals are conjectured to be [normal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), at least in base $10$.

Comment: Nitpick: $g$ does not map to $\mathbb{R}$. What is $71821812...$? An infinitely long string of digits with no decimal point?! That's not a valid representation of any real number. You need the codomain of g/domain of f to be a set of strings (including infinite strings) of digits, not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mike4ty4 Its all hypothetical, _mon ami_.

Comment: @mike4ty4: You mean $g(e)=7182\color{blue}{8182}\dots$. Don't you recognize the decimal part of $e = \color{red}{2}.71828182\dots$?  :)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: Yes, but 71821812... is not a real number. I am saying that he has got the codomain wrong. 71821812... is a string of digits (decimal expansion of e after the decimal point) not a real number.

Comment: @mike4ty4: Ok. But a small nitpick. Where did you get $71821812\dots$? The expansion of $e$ after the decimal point should be $71828182\dots$

Comment: @Tito Piezas III: Typo or misread?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, of course there is a 0 in the decimal expansion of $\pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795\underline{0}2884197...$.

Comment: It was touch and go for a while though, wasn't it?